# error while importing txt file into mallet

Tags: mallet

I have been having trouble converting some txt files to mallet. I keep getting:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line #39843 does not match regex:

and the Line#39843 reads:
24393584    |Title  Validation of a Danish version of the Toronto Extremity Salvage Score questionnaire for  patients with sarcoma in the extremities.The Toronto Extremity Salvage Score (TESS) questionnaire is a selfadministered questionnaire designed to assess physical disability in patients having undergone surgery of the extremities. The aim of this study was to validate a Danish translation of the TESS. The TESS was translated according to international guidelines. A total of 22 consecutive patients attending the regular outpatient control programme were recruited for the study. To test their understanding of the questionnaires, they were asked to describe the meaning of five randomly selected questions from the TESS. The psychometric properties of the Danish version of TESS were tested for validity and reliability. To assess the testretest reliability, the patients filled in an extra TESS questionnaire one week after they had completed the first one. Patients showed good understanding of the questionnaire. There was a good internal consistency for both the upper and lower questionnaire measured by Cronbach's alpha. A BlandAltman plot showed acceptable limits of agreement for both questionnaires in the testretest. There was also good intraclass correlation coefficients for both questionnaires. The validity expressed as Spearman's rank correlation coefficient comparing the TESS with the QLQC30 was 0.89 and 0.90 for the questionnaire on upper and lower extremities, respectively. The psychometric properties of the Danish TESS showed good validity and reliability. not relevant.not relevant.

This happens for a quite a few of the lines and when I remove the line, the rest of the file 
is imported into mallet. What regex expression in this line could be the problem?

thanks,
Priya

Comment: you said regex is causing your issue but I don't see any regex that you have posted.  can you add that?

Answer (score 1):

Mallet has problems handling certain machine symbols, because of bad programming. Try running

```
tr -dc [:alnum:][\ ,.]\\n < ./inputfile.txt > ./inputfilefixed.txt
```

before running mallet. This will remove all non-alphanumerical symbols, which usually solves the problem for me.